# How to generate .iso from the pfsense source code

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I'm trying a custom version of pfsense from its source code in GIT, but I'm having problems.

it does not seem to create this **repo-xxxx-core.sqlite**, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
access repo file(/var/db/pkg/repo-4sense-core.sqlite) failed: No such file or directory
```

**Terminal:**

```
root@:/usr/local/pfsense # ./build.sh iso
>>> Operation ./build.sh has started at Tue Dec 19 14:56:18 UTC 2017
>>> Building image type(s): iso
>>> Cleaning up previous build environment...Please wait!
>>> Cleaning build directories: Done!
>>> Cleaning previously built kernel stage area...Done!
>>> Cleaning previously built images...Done!
>>> Cleaning previous builder logs...Done!
>>> Cleaning of builder environment has finished.
>>> Obtaining FreeBSD sources (RELENG_2_4)...
====>> Removing local changes from git repo https://github.com/pfsense/freebsd-src.git (RELENG_2_4)
====>> Removing leftovers from git repo https://github.com/pfsense/freebsd-src.git (RELENG_2_4)
====>> Retrieving updates from git repo https://github.com/pfsense/freebsd-src.git (RELENG_2_4)
====>> Updating git repo https://github.com/pfsense/freebsd-src.git (RELENG_2_4)
====>> Rebasing git repo https://github.com/pfsense/freebsd-src.git (RELENG_2_4)
>>> Last known commit jim-p - 9af697ce606ce583f406af6987b579a63b7be9a8
Updating 4sense-core repository catalogue...
pkg: Repository 4sense-core load error: access repo file(/var/db/pkg/repo-4sense-core.sqlite) failed: No such file or directory
pkg: http://release-staging.netgate.com/ce/packages/4sense_v2_4_2_amd64-core/meta.txz: Operation timed out
repository 4sense-core has no meta file, using default settings
pkg: http://release-staging.netgate.com/ce/packages/4sense_v2_4_2_amd64-core/packagesite.txz: Operation timed out
Unable to update repository 4sense-core
Updating 4sense repository catalogue...
pkg: Repository 4sense load error: access repo file(/var/db/pkg/repo-4sense.sqlite) failed: No such file or directory
pkg: http://release-staging.netgate.com/ce/packages/4sense_v2_4_2_amd64-4sense_v2_4_2/meta.txz: Operation timed out
repository 4sense has no meta file, using default settings
pkg: http://release-staging.netgate.com/ce/packages/4sense_v2_4_2_amd64-4sense_v2_4_2/packagesite.txz: Operation timed out
Unable to update repository 4sense
Error updating repositories!
>>> LOGFILE set to /usr/local/pfsense/logs/buildworld.amd64.
>>> Tue Dec 19 15:02:36 UTC 2017 - Starting build world for amd64 architecture...
====>> ERROR: __MAKE_CONF is pointing to a nonexistent file /usr/local/pfsense/tmp/FreeBSD-src/release/conf/4sense_make.conf

####################################
Something went wrong, check errors!
####################################

NOTE: a lot of times you can run './build.sh --clean-builder' to resolve.

Log saved on /usr/local/pfsense/logs/buildworld.amd64

Terminated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mean you forgot to rename `.conf` files in `/release/conf/`, in FreeBSD-src

you should have a look to https://github.com/Augustin-FL/building-pfsense-iso-from-source#freebsd-source